# field image in report

Tags: reporting-services

in the table I have a field true or false and I would like to display an image if it is true and another if it's false.
What would be the expression

View my table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to display the image in a textbox, and assuming that you are using images that you have embedded in the report (i.e. you have inserted images into the report and are not using an external reference or a database image) called image1 and image2, and assuming that the name of the field with the True/False value is Mailing, select the text box to hold the image and then find the BackgroundImage property in the Properties window. Expand it - set source to Embedded and set Value to the following expression:

```
=iif(Fields!Mailing.Value = "True", image1, image2)
```

If your field value is a bit data type, your expression looks like this:

```
=iif(Fields!Mailing.Value = 1, image1, image2)
```